# Rails store millions of small images. GridFs?

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, gridfs

I need to store millions of small images 0,1kb-8Mb. I heard about gridfs but I can read in docu "For documents in a MongoDB collection, you should always use GridFS for storing files larger than 16 MB.". So it is not good solution for many small files ? I am looking for the fastest way to store images (and other binary files)

Comment: Why do you need them stored in the db. Couldn't you use s3 or other similar.

Comment: No, I want to use only my own server. I want to use db because I think it is faster than filesystems.

Comment: If you store files in your DB you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: Rather not :) There are special databases like gridfs to store files more efficiently than filesystem because they store every files in one file and if you have thousands files it will be faster.

Comment: What's your question then if you've already figured out gridfs is faster than fs?

Comment: Because I am not sure.

Comment: Did you end up getting anything working? - The obvious advantage would be the ability to run something like Assets.filter(whatever).delete and have tens or hundreds of thousands of files being deleted far more efficiently than looping over each asset and deleting the file from the filesystem one at a time. From what I saw, actually serving the files from gridfs is slower than from a filesystem though.

Comment: No, I've not found good answer. How did you serve files ? Selecting from MySQL file names and reading from gridfs ? What exacly have you tested ?